# How can I search conan for packages by description text?

Tags: c++, conan, package-management

I've not used Conan before. I've now installed it, and I basically know how to install a package with it, but - I need to find packages.

I've gone here: https://bintray.com/conan/conan-center

and there's a search interface, but it seems to ignore package descriptions and only try to match package names. This is really problematic, for obvious reasons.

My question: Other than scrolling through packages, what can I do to search for packages by matching description text?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new interface, including a new search service, in https://conan.io/center/. The search might be a bit better, but not yet indexing the full description fields.

The packages are now generated from pull requests submitted to the [conan-center-index repo](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index), and issues specific to the Web UI, including the search functionality can use the "[conan.io/center](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20label%3Aconan.io%2Fcenter)" label. Some of the current suggestions include navigating by topics. Indexing the descriptions will be done, hopefully soon.

In the meantime, cloning and grepping the [conan-center-index repo](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index) is a very convenient/pragmatic way to find things including descriptions

Comment: Search via the first link is rather unfruitful. I searched for "command" and found nothing, for example. Still, +1.

Comment: Yeah, totally, the new front-end is not very mature, still will be the place that will receive future improvements. Unless you know more or less the package name, better grep the repo. Thanks!